# Reading Serial Data sent from PC to Arduino with another Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to sniff the Serial Communication between the PC and Arduino MEGA 2560. For trying to check what my PC is sending to my Arduino. I am using another Arduino MEGA 2560 to read this data since my serial monitor is busy.

To this I have connected RX pin of my arduino to RX Pin of my second arduino and both have common ground. In this way i thought i can use serial monitor of my second arduino to see the data what my pc is sending to Arduino.

But when i upload the program to Arduino, I am getting the following error

> avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout avrdude:
> stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage():
> timeout avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout avrdude:
> stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage():
> timeout avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with
> programmer

I dont have any problems when i use only one Arduino.

One Arduino uses COM Port 4 and other uses COM Port 5. I am not sure what is going wrong. I googled this problem and found few things but none of them were quiet working for me.

The main issue which i am not sure is if i can use Arduino IDE instance twice(one for each arduino with different com port) and check what my pc is sending to first arduino with the help of second arduino.

Comment: You will have better luck getting an answer at [arduino.se].

Comment: Get a JTAG or ISP programmer and quit using your serial port for this, if you want it available.

Answer (score 0):

By connecting the RX pins of two Arduino's, you have effectively shorted TX pins of their internal USB to serial adapters. Thankfully Arduino Mega has Serial1, Serial2 and Serial3 ports, which are completely free.

EDIT: If you want just to sniff the Serial port with other Arduino, you could flash a blank sketch to the sniffing Arduino and connect its TX pin of Serial0 to the RX pin on the main Arduino.

Btw, it's not a question for stackoverflow.com